# How to return a list of a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume I input list containing [1,2,3,4].
How do I make it so it returns another list only containing the first and last entry ([1,4]).

Comment: That's not a list of lists - that's a list containing only part of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

To returns another list only containing the first and last entry you may

```py
    a=[1,2,3,4]
    b=[a[0], a[-1]]
    b
    [1, 4]
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation to this? That would be helpful to the OP.